# How can I increase the font size for tmux status line?

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to increase the font size in the tmux status line independent of the size in the panes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the terminal output is character-based rather than pixel-based, this is not possible. The only way to get larger characters is to draw them using lines and points (“ASCII art”) on multiple lines/columns.

Comment: So to clarify, you cannot display multiple console fonts on a screen? E.g. I can't have default8x9 for one line and Lat15-VGA16 for another?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it is.